# Byte array to image view

Tags: arrays, kotlin, bitmap, aes

I am trying to Encrypt the Image with Aes and its working successfully

But once I have the final decrypted Byte array I am unable to set to image

```
  val bitmap = (imge.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
  val width = bitmap.width
  val height = bitmap.height
  val decryptedText: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(bytes)

                
  val configBmp = Bitmap.Config.valueOf(bitmap.config.name)
  val bitmap_tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, configBmp)
  val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(decryptedText)
  bitmap_tmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)

  img.setImageBitmap(bitmap_tmp)
```

decrypted text is the decrypted byte array , Once I have this with the help of unencrypted image I am getting the width and height and using that to turn the byte array back  into a image.

However I tried to do without using the stats of original image like height and length and bitmap by the help of below code.

```
 val decryptedText: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(bytes)

 val ol = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decryptedText, 0, decryptedText.size)
 img.setImageBitmap(ol)
```

However this doesn't work and in Log cat it shows:-

```
D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
```

App is not crashing but I am unable to get decrypted image in my image view

How do I convert the byte array to bitmap so Image can be set.

Encryption Function:-

```
   fun encryption(imageView: ImageView, name: String, uid: String) {
        val bitmap = (imge.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap

        val size = bitmap.rowBytes * bitmap.height
        val byteBuffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size)
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer)
        val byteArray = byteBuffer.array()

        Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles").document("YHMauLouORRtrYBV2h4dHJ5A0s72")
            .update("key", "$secretKey1")

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
        val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(secretKey1, "AES")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec)
        val z = cipher.doFinal(byteArray)
        val file = File.createTempFile("$name", null)
        file.writeBytes(z)
        Log.d("first", "quick")
        val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
            .getReference("/image/0XhL4jD4XCemk38rcRkIEjJMgjh2/Aadhar/")
        storageReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file))
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }
```

Decryption Function:-

```
 val bitmap = (imge.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
        val width = bitmap.width
        val height = bitmap.height
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
        val SecretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(secretKey1, "AES")
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, SecretKeySpec)

        val storageRef =
            FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference?.child("/image/0XhL4jD4XCemk38rcRkIEjJMgjh2/Aadhar/")
        val localfile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".txt")
        storageRef.getFile(localfile)
            .addOnSuccessListener {

                val bytes = localfile.readBytes()
                val decryptedText: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(bytes)

                val configBmp = Bitmap.Config.valueOf(bitmap.config.name)
                val bitmap_tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, configBmp)
                val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(decryptedText)
                bitmap_tmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)


                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap_tmp)
```

Comment: how are you encrypting and decrypting the image?

Comment: Breaking the image into a byte array and applying encryption and decryption on it

Comment: Can you share your encryption and decryption code?

Comment: Added the encryption and decryption function

Comment: Have you tested that encrypting and decrypting gives you the same byte array as the original? (Ideally running a bunch of tests, maybe with randomised data.) If it doesn't give you the same data then you've got a problem there! If it does, then the encryption part is irrelevant